# React- is it better to conditionally render larger components or smaller children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

If multiple components in a tree of components should render differently based on some shared data (current user, dark or light mode), is it better to create different higher level large components that conditionally render? Or is it better the have the lower level small components conditionally render?

For example, lets say I have a `<ProfileSection>` component made up of many smaller components like `<Avatar>`, `<CoverImage>` etc..

[image]

When the current user of the profile is logged in, it should render with edit buttons like this:[image]

**Is it better to conditionally render two different profile sections?**

`{isAuth ? <EditableProfileSection>:<ProfileSection>}`

**Or is better to render one `<ProfileSection>` and conditionally render its children using react context**

Ex:

`{ isAuth && <EditProfileButton>}`

`{isAuth ? <EditableAvatar> : <Avatar>}`

It feels like the second way is more correct because if you had two different higher level components they could get out of sync if you made changes to one. I think I just answered my question... I guess I'll post this anyways because maybe it will help someone.

Comment: I agree with the second way because it feels like a waste to copy a whole component to make a few changes.

Comment: I think a good place to start would be [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html). Try to *also* think more abstractly about your UI and what it means to visually display parts of it (or not). In this case an `edit` prop seems enough to conditionally render some additional UI elements, like an "edit profile"  and "edit image" buttons, since abstractly that is what they represent. Ultimately you want your code (and by extension, your components) to be as ***DRY*** as possible.